# not able to see web part on anonymous site in SharePoint 2010

Tags: web-part, anonymous-authentication

i am not able to see custom web part on my anonymous site in sharepoint 2010.
when i add out of box web part it is visible but custom web part is not visible.

please help me to resolve this.

Comment: As Anders rightly says - more info needed.  What is the web part doing?  Post some source code and add some more detail.

Comment: did you publish the page after adding your web part? is the web part throwing an error?

Comment: i dont know how to publish page after adding web part .
can u help me to figure out this.

Comment: thanx it is working now.
i published my page and im able to see my web part.
thanx to all for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just edited the page and there was a publish option on ribbon .
i clicked on it.
after that it starts working.

Answer (score 0):

to better be able to help you debugging this we need more info

do you have the custom web part working somewhere (for example in non-anonymous dev. environment)?

Comment: no, my web part is not working anywhere.
for testing purpose i created a simle 'hello world!!' web part .

Comment: if web part isnt working anywhere, it could be a number of reasons. Please post full source.

Comment: Also add any related errors from ULS log (use ULS Viewer http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer to monitor log while you add web part) to get an idea on what happens.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your url just append contents=1 like(http://.....aspx?contents=1) and see whether your webpart is loaded on page or not.

Comment: my problem is that when i sign in with any account it shows the web part but it does not show for anonymous access.

Comment: my web part is not visible on enterprise search template site but it is visible on basic search page template site.

is there is any problem with enterprise search template for anonymous access?

Comment: Have a look at here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/b989fab4-0d54-4a10-9eeb-bd0fefbfd8aa  Same situation as you are facing :)

Comment: Or enable Anonymous access in Enterprise Portal.

Comment: i checked  social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/… url but i dont know how to publish or approve web part.
can u help me to do this?